# StyleCop property location inside a file

Tags: c#, stylecop, roslyn-code-analysis

Is there a way to set StyleCop analyzer to use allow properties to be before constructors in a file.

From this

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

To this

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {

    }
}
```

I am using [StyleCop analyzer for Roslyn](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers)

Comment: You warning you are getting - what ID is it? SA0001? Something else?

Comment: @mjwills It's SA1201 But the problem is this rule is way too broad to suppress as a whole. I was wondering if you could customize it to support different order of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could just suppress SA1201 "elements must appear in the correct order".

Resharper lets you set file layout in the way out want but I don't think stylecop will let you set a specific order.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't want to suppress it. I would like to have some rule regarding placement of properties just have this in different order.

Comment: Is there a way for me to set the style.json for the style cop code analyzer?

Comment: @FilipCordas I'd suggest raising that as an issue on their github repo.